# Alt Keys in a Windows clipboard

Tags: c++, character-encoding

I'm having a problem with my class, it's made to:
- get a text from the clipboard
- toss it into a vector table (1 text line == 1 table record)
- join it back into one string
- paste it into the clipboard

Unfortunately, I'm having a trouble with chars like → (Alt+26), whenever I'm loading a string containing such char, after pasting it back into the clipboard I'm getting broken char in it's place.

I'm using Code Block with GNU GCC Compiler on Windows 7.
Additionally, → char is displayed correctly in a console (with default settings) using cout.

library.hpp:

```
#ifndef library
#define library

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string_regex.hpp>

using namespace std;


//used in string.find function
const size_t NotFound=(size_t)-1;

#endif
```

copy_paste.hpp

```
#ifndef copy_paste_hpp
#define copy_paste_hpp

#include "library.hpp"

class copy_paste
{
private:
    vector < string > text;
    string fullText;

    //splitting and joining fullText
    bool prepareText();
    bool prepareFullText();

    //integration with Windows Clipboard
    bool setClip();
    string getClip();

public:
    copy_paste();

    vector <string> getText();
    void setText(vector<string> a);

};

#endif
```

copy_paste.cpp

```
#ifndef copy_paste_cpp
#define copy_paste_cpp

#include "copy_paste.hpp" //#include "declaration.hpp"


copy_paste::copy_paste()
{
 fullText="d";
};


    bool copy_paste::prepareText()
    {
        if(text.empty()==false)
            text.clear();

        if(fullText=="")
            return 0;

    split( text, fullText,  boost::algorithm::is_any_of("\n")); // (1)
    return true;
    };


    bool copy_paste::prepareFullText()
    {
        fullText="";
        for(unsigned int i=0; i<text.size();i++)
        {
            fullText+=text[i];
            fullText+="\n";
        }
       // cout<<fullText;
        return true;
    };

string copy_paste::getClip()
{
    string res;
    if( !OpenClipboard( 0 ) )
         return res;

    HANDLE hMem = GetClipboardData( CF_OEMTEXT );
    if( !hMem )
    {
        CloseClipboard();
        return res;
    }
    char * p =( char * ) GlobalLock( hMem );
    if( !p )
    {
        CloseClipboard();
        return res;
    }
    res = p;
    GlobalUnlock( hMem );
    CloseClipboard();

    return res;
}

bool copy_paste::setClip()
{
    HANDLE hMem = GlobalAlloc( GMEM_MOVEABLE, fullText.length() + 1 );
    if( !hMem )
         return false;

    char * p =( char * ) GlobalLock( hMem );
    if( !p )
    {
        GlobalFree( hMem );
        return false;
    }
    for( size_t i = 0; i <= fullText.length(); ++i )
         p[ i ] = fullText[ i ];

    GlobalUnlock( hMem );
    if( !OpenClipboard( 0 ) )
    {
        GlobalFree( hMem );
        return false;
    }
    EmptyClipboard();
    SetClipboardData( CF_OEMTEXT, hMem );
    CloseClipboard();
    return true;
}


    vector<string> copy_paste::getText()
    {
        fullText=getClip();
        prepareText();
        return text;
    };

    void copy_paste::setText(vector<string> a)
    {
        text=a;
        prepareFullText();
        setClip();
    };



#endif
```

Comment: What you know about text has been obsolete for 25 years.  [This blog post](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) is a decent start.

Comment: Thanks! I'm just reading it. I've tried wstrings, console output and so on, but I done that without real knowledge how does it works.